# MySql REPLACE function in query evaluates only once, not on every row

Tags: mysql

On a server running MySql 5.0.27, with a very simple query that uses REPLACE --

```
SELECT familyname, replace('{0} test' , '{0}', `familyname`) AS  `formattedname`
FROM family
```

I get a result where the second column has only been evaluated once:

```
familyname   formattedname
Andersen     Andersen test
Baker        Andersen test
Charles      Andersen test
```

On a development machine running MySql 5.5.9, same query and data, the results are as I would expect:

```
Andersen     Andersen test
Baker        Baker test
Charles      Charles test
```

Is this a MySql bug in the older version, or is there some other possibility (a server misconfiguration, an index error, etc?).

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d476/3/0). What is the datatype of your `familyname` column?

Comment: sqlfiddle uses mysql 5.5 and the bug apparently only happens on 5.0

Comment: @Vatev, oh I misread, I did not see the OP was running 5.0.27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. It was reported [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44583).
Either you can live with it, or you need to upgrade at least to MySQL 5.1.

And if your software is compatible, why not upgrade to MySQL 5.5?

I found the bug report using the [search engine](http://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=REPLACE&bug_type%5b%5d=Server&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Compiling&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Packaging&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Installing&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Config+Wizard&bug_type%5b%5d=C+API&bug_type%5b%5d=Client&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Backup&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Charsets&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+DDL&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+DML&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Types&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Errors&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+FTS&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+General&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+GIS&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+I_S&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Locking&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Memcached&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Optimizer&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Options&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Parser&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Partition&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Performance+Schema&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Pluggable+Authentication&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+PS&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Privileges&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Query+Cache&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Replication&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+RBR&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+SE+API&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+SP&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Tests&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Logging&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Tracing&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+UDF&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Windows&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+XA&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+XML&bug_type%5b%5d=libmysqld&bug_type%5b%5d=Server%3A+Docs&status%5b%5d=Active&status%5b%5d=Under+Development&status%5b%5d=In+QA&status%5b%5d=Open&status%5b%5d=Closed&status%5b%5d=Duplicate&status%5b%5d=Analyzing&status%5b%5d=Verified&status%5b%5d=In+progress&status%5b%5d=Patch+pending&status%5b%5d=In+review&status%5b%5d=Patch+approved&status%5b%5d=Patch+queued&status%5b%5d=Need+Merge&status%5b%5d=Documenting&status%5b%5d=QA+testing&status%5b%5d=QA+review&status%5b%5d=Post-fix+test+fail&status%5b%5d=Need+Doc+Info&status%5b%5d=To+be+fixed+later&status%5b%5d=Won%27t+fix&status%5b%5d=Can%27t+repeat&status%5b%5d=No+Feedback&status%5b%5d=Need+Feedback&status%5b%5d=Stale&status%5b%5d=Fresh&status%5b%5d=Not+a+Bug&status%5b%5d=Unsupported&status%5b%5d=All&severity=all&limit=30&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&tags=&similar=&target=&defect_class=all&workaround_viability=all&impact=all&fix_risk=all&fix_effort=all&triageneeded=) in the Mysql bugs database.

Comment: Thanks; I'd searched the bug list but using poor search terms.